# Custom service class with a ThreadPoolExecutor killed when app is off

Tags: android, multithreading, locationlistener, threadpoolexecutor, background-service

I need to execute multipe tasks in parallel inside a custom service to get these working :
- Location service and activity recognition API.
- Geofence API and REST API calls. 
I'm new to threads in java and android, and i found that the best way to implement this is to use a ThreadPoolExecutor instead of making my own thread classes and dealing with all the Handler Looper stuff.

When i execute my app, the service starts, Location updates and activity updates works fine inside a thread. but, when i close the app, the service restarts (when `return START_STICKY;`) and the thread is not working anymore.When (`return START_NOT_STICKY;`), the service disappears.
(In my case, i can't use startforeground())
I'm using this library([smart-location-lib](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib)) for location and activity updates.
**- Here's my custom service code :**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private ThreadPoolExecutor mDecodeThreadPool;
    private BlockingQueue<Runnable> mDecodeWorkQueue;

    private int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 1;
    private final TimeUnit KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

    public LocationService () {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location services created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDecodeWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        mDecodeThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2, // Initial pool size
                NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2, // Max pool size
                KEEP_ALIVE_TIME,
                KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT,
                mDecodeWorkQueue);    
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location services started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mDecodeThreadPool.execute(new LocationRunnable(getApplicationContext()));
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Log.v("LOW MEMORY", "|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location services stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mDecodeThreadPool.shutdown();
        mDecodeThreadPool.shutdownNow();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**- Here's my Runnable class code :**

```
public class LocationRunnable implements Runnable, OnLocationUpdatedListener, OnActivityUpdatedListener {

     SmartLocation smartLocation;
     public LocationRunnable(Context ctx) {
          smartLocation = new SmartLocation.Builder(ctx).logging(true).build();

     }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("THREAD", "THREAD STARTED");
        startLocation();
     }


    private void startLocation() {
        smartLocation.location().start(this);
        smartLocation.activity().start(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityUpdated(DetectedActivity detectedActivity) {
        if (detectedActivity != null) {
            Log.v("ACTIVITY", "ACTIVITY UPDATED");
        } else {
            Log.v("ACTIVITY", "NULL");
        }

    }
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
        Log.v("LOCATION", "LOCATION UPDATED" + i++);
    }

    private String getNameFromType(DetectedActivity activityType) {
        switch (activityType.getType()) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                return "in_vehicle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                return "on_bicycle";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                return "on_foot";
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                return "still";
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                return "tilting";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

}
```

I'm not really sure if this is the right or the best way to get what i need.
**Any help is greatly appreciated !**

Comment: You don't "close the app" in Android. Please explain **exactly** what you mean by "close the app".

Comment: It's just the multitasking button (the one that shows the opened apps). So, i swipe it off and it's supposed to keep running in background.

Comment: That terminates the background process, as if the process were terminated due to low memory conditions.

Comment: Yes, but still when the service restarts (return START_STICKY;), location updates don't work anymore.

Comment: I don't know what "location updates don't work anymore" means exactly. You are going to need to set up the location updates again, which is in code that isn't in your question. Your process can be terminated at any point, even with the service, so this is a scenario that your app needs to be able to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the question is old, but it might be of help to others.

I think it is due to the fact that the code from Runnable.run() exits immediately, thereby ending the parent thread, so that the changes in location no longer have an object to be posted to.

> smartLocation.location().start(this);  // this <-- is the Runnable

And the reason you get update until restart might be due to garbage collection not clearing up the no longer used Runnable object or some existing reference to it within your code.